# Codeigniter URL remapping to remove segment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter website where the request urls take the form:

```
example.com/segment1/segment2/segment3 where:

segment 1 is a folder name
segment 2 is a controller name
segment 3 is a function name
```

I want to remap these requests to:

```
example.com/segment2/segment3
```

I have tried this in my*routes.php* config:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "$2/$3/$1";
```

The reqyest that shows up in my browser's address bar is unchanged :

example.com/segment1/segment2/segment3

How can I fix this?

Comment: So you want when a user enters "example.com/segment1/segment2/segment3" into the browser it will actually call "example.com/index.php/segment2/segment3" ???

Comment: David, I'd like it to generate example.com/segment2/segment3 the index.php is already been taken out

Comment: Just add the 2nd line from my answer to be above the section in your .htacccess file that is removing the index.php

Comment: I'll remove the "index.php" from my answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your .htaccess file (as you mentioned your folder is static):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?/(.*)?$   your-folder-here/$1/$2   [L,NC]
```

Comment: Sorry David, I want this done by codeigniter before the request hits the browser. I already have an htacess file which is making other modifications, but AFAIK the htacess file takes the inputted request and modifies it, but this leaves the initial request in the browser window which I want to make look prettier. Thanks - Bill

Comment: Hi Bill, well codeigniter is not going to change what you type in the browser (like a redirect) using routes, like what you are attempting. Most of the time, the idea is to give a rule that takes the preferred way of entering the URL and routes it to the ugly real location. Basically, the user enters a pretty URL and secretly gets taken to the real (ugly) location. So which is the pretty URL and which is the ugly URL here?

Comment: David ugly URL: example.com/segment1/segment2/segment3 pretty URL: example.com/segment2/segment3. remember that segment1 is a constant (  a folder name )

Comment: awww...ok then your problem is you need to reverse the way you have entered your codeigniter route. Updating answer...

Comment: See my answer now. It's looking for users to type in "controller/function" and it will route to "your-folder/controller/function".

Comment: And...Remember the idea with pretty urls is that your site has these as links everywhere. Nobody ever knows about the ugly urls because you don't provide links with them (plus they would get messed up with the routing as they are assumed to all be pretty urls now)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30663/discussion-between-user61629-and-david-graham)

Answer (score 0):

This will work but this would overwrite every possible URLS.

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller_name/$1/$2';
```

In order to make other controllers work, you have to define before the above statement

```
$route['other_controller_1/(:any)'] = 'other_controller_1/$1';
$route['other_controller_2/(:any)'] = 'other_controller_2/$1';
```

[URI Routing : Codeigniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)